# Path of current document in [Libre|Open]Office

Tags: macros, libreoffice, libreoffice-basic

How can I determine the path of the currently open document in an OpenOffice or LibreOffice document? I want to forward the path to an external application.

More specifically I want to launch an external player from impress with a video file in full-screen mode:

```
Shell("/usr/bin/mplayer", 2, """ -fs"" some-file-in-same-dir-as-document.mp4")
```

For the last parameter I would need the path to the currently opened document in order to append it. Not specifying the path results in referring to the current path (as given by the `CurDir()` function) which is something different.

Is there actually a good reference for LibreOffice Macros? The only relatively good (but hard to search) document I have found is "[OpenOffice Macros Explained](http://www.pitonyak.org/book/)" by Andrew Pitonyak.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the meantime I have found a feasible solution. Look here:

```
Sub RunSomeMovie
    GlobalScope.BasicLibraries.loadLibrary("Tools")
    Shell("/usr/bin/mplayer -fs ", 2, "" & Tools.Strings.DirectoryNameoutofPath(ThisComponent.getURL(),"/") & "/media/somemovie.mp4")
End Sub
```

Comment: I use ubuntu and start a document from symlink. ThisComponent.getURL() returns symlink' path instead of location of the document. Is this a bug? LibreOffice 6.4.7.2.

Answer (score 6):

to get the current document path you use this simple command:

```
ThisComponent.getURL()
```

CurDir() is simply not reliable for all OS
BTW I found that info in the Pitonyak book you cited that I didn't knew and found very precious so thanks for sharing it.

Comment: Thank you! I can confirm that this is the answer I was looking for. To be honest I have to admit that I have found a solution in the meantime (please see below).

Comment: This solution is KISS :-)  
Nevertheless it returns a string like: **file:///home/Libs/Util/File.ods**  
And many times at least me in Linux need something like: **/home/Libs/Util/File.ods**  
The solution is also easy.  
I use something like: **Right(ThisComponent.getURL(), Len(ThisComponent.getURL()) - 7)**

Answer (score 4):

I'm working with LibreOffice 4.2.0.4 and the following Code works for me:

```
    Dim Dir as String
    GlobalScope.BasicLibraries.loadLibrary("Tools")
    Dir = Tools.Strings.DirectoryNameoutofPath(ThisComponent.url, "/")
```

The variable "dir" contains now the path of the current document.

Answer (score 3):

Document has a location only if it is saved (or opened from a saved). In addition a Form opened from within LibreOffice Base does not have by its own a location. Only the odt has a location. Hence although:

ThisComponent.hasLocation()

returns True, the location is an empty string (consider it as a bug).
To obtain the location, in such cases, you have to access the "Parent":

ThisComponent.Parent.hasLocation() (or ThisComponent.Parent.getURL())

Of course you then have to "traslate" it to readable with:
Tools.Strings.DirectoryNameoutofPath